# Button background not filling completely on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

So I have a button, but here's the issue. On Firefox *only* does it not completely fill up. As seen here

[image]

This is what it *should* look like

[image]

I'm not really sure what to do. Here's the CSS

```
.button-panel .button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 55px;
  font-size: 27px;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Avenir Next';
  display: inline-block;    
  font-weight: 300;
  background-color: #6699FF;
  outline: 3px solid #6699FF;
  line-height: 59px;
}
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/h7PXe/

Comment: Looks fine in Firefox here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do `height: 100%`. You need to do this or else the browser won't know what to set the height to.

```
.button-panel .button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 55px;
  font-size: 27px;
 letter-spacing: 0.05em;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 font-family: 'Avenir Next';
 display: inline-block;    
 font-weight: 300;
 background-color: #6699FF;
 outline: 3px solid #6699FF;
 line-height: 59px;
 height: 100%
}
```

And a [demo](http://jsbin.com/bopeqini/2/edit).

Answer (score 0):

Reason why it showing up is that you use line-height bigger than height of element.

Here you can see how box model is woking and were are outlines:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6J6n.png

You can achieve the same look without using basic properties (then it will work in every browser)

```
.button-panel .button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 7px 0 5px;
    border: 3px solid #6699FF;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Avenir Next';
    font-size: 27px;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    text-align: center; 
    background-color: #6699FF;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h7PXe/1/